# Pandas groupby().sem reorders by columns after adding a non-numeric column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, standard-error

first time asking a question:
I'm using

```
print(df.groupby(['SIDE']).sem())
```

get correct results when "Sector" column, the last in the data set has a heading but no data but after populating non-numeric data in the column it returns data frame with columns in different order. I'm also using

```
df.groupby('SIDE').mean()
df.groupby('SIDE').std()
```

with no issues on the same data, feeling stuck, seems like a bug?

[image]

[image: After adding non-numeric data to column]

Comment: I'm confused!  Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also [how to make a reproducible example with pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: @AndrewBunker Thou shalt not post images. Thou shalt post it as text!

Comment: Yes, that looks like a bug. A workaround would be `df.groupby(['SIDE']).sem()[df.columns]`

Comment: Thanks guys for the help and intro to the posting protocol. Ayhan, your post helped, I finally used the reindex_like function to work around.